# What is the purpose of the sleep() function in a Thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I often see Sleep(N) after a thread starts or sometimes I see Thread::Sleep(N); where N is in milliseconds. Is it meant to put the current thread in sleep so that another thread can start?

I appreciate any response

Comment: without mention of a specific library we can't be sure, but typically it yields the thread for a period of time, often with the objective of allowing the underlying scheduler to give other threads an opportunity to run. Contrast this with [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)

Comment: `On Windows ::Sleep(0)` is documented to yield: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use of `sleep()` function (and it's friends) usually indicate design flaw. The rare exceptions are sleeps used in debugging.

The common misguided usages of `sleep` include an attempt to time events to a certain time (bad, because no one guarantees that sleep will take exactly that many units as prescribed on non-RT systems), attempt to wait for some events (bad, because to wait for event you should use specific waiting functions available with your threading library) or an attempt to yield resources - bad, because if you have nothing to do, just exit the thread.

Answer (score 3):

Sleep puts the thread in non-runnable state for the specified amount of time or until the process is woken up by a signal.

When a thread is in non-runnable state, the OS scheduler won't schedule the thread into the run queue, and the OS forces a thread/context switch so that another runnable task (thread/process) can run instead.

Comment: Not neccessarily. If thread hadn't used up it's slice, it might as well continue running.

Comment: @SergeyA That is really dependent on the underlying threading implementation. Windows for example will always relinquish the remainder of its slice.

Comment: @SergeyA: If a thread asks to be put to sleep, the thread won't "continue running". Unless by "it" you meant "the process"? Then yes I agree with you, the switch may be to another thread in the same process.

Comment: @Ics, that's why **might**.

Comment: @LieRyan, no, thread switch is not guaranteed in general (might be in your specific thread support lib).

Comment: @SergeyA: I never claimed that thread switch is guaranteed to switch to another thread. Any sane sleep implementations would always consider sleep to be a context switch opportunity. But just because a context switch opportunity happens doesn't mean that another thread will be run. If the current thread happens to be the highest priority thread that's in runnable state or if the scheduler thinks that context switch is not beneficial at the time, then it's perfectly fine for sleep to just immediately return to the current thread for the rest of its time slice.

Comment: *and the OS forces a thread/context switch* - those are your own words.

Comment: @SergeyA: I don't know how you read that, but "forces context switch" is not the same as "guarantees that a different thread will be run".

Answer (score 2):

As I know, we use `sleep()` for the cases below:

1) Simulation. When you need simulate some situation to test your code, you may use `sleep()`.
For example, you are designing a module, which is to be a server. Now you need to test your server with a case where a client sends a heavy request of 5 sec. To do this test, you don't need a real client. What you just need is to simulate a client with `sleep(5000)`.

2) Give other threads chance of execution --- as you mentioned. But please attention: `sleep()` will hold the lock.

3) Save the resource of CPU.
For example, in the mode of non-blocking of socket, you may code like this:

```
while(true)
{
    sleep(200);
    res = accept(mysocket, NONBLOCKING);
    if (getMsg(res))
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This is non-blocking mode, when it executes `accept`, it will check if there is some messages immediately. If no message, it continue.
In this case, if we don't add a `sleep()` like above, this code will consume lots of resource of CPU for nothing (just a infinite loop). So we add a `sleep()` so that other threads or other processes can use CPU. In other words, CPU is used more efficient now.
By the way, the network card has its own cache, so if a client sends a message to the code above and at the same time, the code starts to sleep for 1 second, it wouldn't be a problem because after 1 second, the message is still there (in the cache), so the code could get it. But, if in this 1 second, there lots of clients sending messages, the code can miss the messages because 1 second is too long to process messages fast. In a word, you must make sure that the received messages can't fill up the cache in 1 second. Otherwise, sleep shorter or process messages faster.

Answer (score 1):

`Sleep(0)` will give up the current time slice to another process if there is a process with a greater priority which is ready to schedule. If there is no process to schedule the current process will return immediately.
`Sleep(n)` where n > 0 will give up unconditionally the current time slice to another process.

[reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thread sleep functions are usually meant to block a particular thread's execution for a at least the provided time, usually, in order to let other threads run without any kind of "interference" from it. It may block for more than the provided time due to scheduling or resource contention delays. It does not, however make the sleeping thread release its locks, if any! They are frequently used for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `Thread::Sleep(N);` will only delays the program's execution, normally waiting for external resources to be there... this was a very common way in low-level/old languages like Asm, where no OOP was able and where programs where run sequentially. Nowadays are interfaces, callbacks, multi thread, notifications. and is just a bad habit to use such techniques...